# Regex - Allow dash character in body text but not at start or end

Tags: regex

How can I allow one subsequent dash character in the body part but not at start or end?

https://regex101.com/r/D8MAXP/8/

One subsequent example: https://regex101.com/r/D8MAXP/9/

Regex

```
^((https?):\/\/)?(www.)?([a-z0-9-])+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$
```

Allow:

```
http://www.b-c.de
https://www.b-c.de
www.b-c.de
b-c.de
```

Don't allow:

```
https://www.foufos-.gr
http://www.foufos-.gr
https://-foufos.gr
http://foufos-.gr
www.-foufos.gr
www.foufos-.gr
www.-foufos.gr
foufos-.gr
-foufos.gr
```

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/rfwzJI/1 or https://regex101.com/r/IGUDo9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching the `-` in the character class, you could take it out and use a repeating group prepending the hyphen before the character class

Use a `*` to repeat it 0+ times or a `?` to match it zero or 1 times.

For the example data in the question, you might use

```
^((https?):\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*(?:\.[a-z]+)+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/slj8rJ/1)

For all the links in the regex101 example, you might use for example 2 negative lookaheads:

```
^(?!ww?\.)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?!.*\.www\b)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*(?:\.[a-z]+)+(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!ww?\.)` Assert not starting with 1 or 2 times a `w` char followed by a .
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` Optionally match the protocol part
- `(?:www\.)?` Optionally match `www.`
- `(?!.*\.www\b)` Assert that what is on the right is not again `www.`
- `[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*` Match chars a-z0-9 optionally repeated by a - and again chars a-z0-9
- `(?:\.[a-z]+)+` Repeat 1+ times a dot and 1+ chars a-z
- `(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `/` and 1+ times any of the listed followed by an optional question mark
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DKgVzj/1)